# How to upload images and video to a web server?

Tags: c#, .net, ftpwebrequest

I have the following code. The upload was successfully but the images and videos are broken. I think the problem is because the encoding set to `UTF8`. How do I upload images and videos to the web server in C#?

```
private static void Upload(string ftpFilePath, string file)
    {
        FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(ftpFilePath);

        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;

        request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(Properties.Settings.Default.FtpUser, Properties.Settings.Default.FtpPass);

        using (Stream fileStream = File.OpenRead(file))
        using (Stream ftpStream = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            fileStream.CopyTo(ftpStream);
        }

        FtpWebResponse response = null;

        try
        {
            response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

            // Output message on screen
            Log.Write($"{request.Method} {ftpFilePath}", Log.Status.UPLOADED);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Output message on screen
            Log.Write($"FTP UPLOAD: {response.StatusCode} - {ex.Message}", Log.Status.ERROR);
        }
    }
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: @FaizanRabbani Actually there is no error but broken images and videos. I was able to fix the image with updated code from my question post. Video still remain broken.

Comment: You don't need to load the entire file into a byte array - in fact this will fail if the file is larger than 2GB (and even on 64-bit systems, `System.Array` cannot exceed 4 billion elements). You should use `Stream.CopyTo` instead.

Comment: @Dai Thanks for the tips. This is very helpful. Revised my code again. Any idea how to get the video working?

Comment: What do you mean by "broken"? What exactly is wrong? If you re-download the files how do they compare to the originals before they were uploaded?

Comment: @Dai it's 404. However, I can see the video file on the web server with a right path. Downloaded the video from server and just played fine.

Comment: @JasonTang You probably just need to add the MIME type to your web.config: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/staticcontent/mimemap

Comment: @Dai I am not sure if you can add a MIME type to the app.config as this is a console application. I'll give it a try. I was able to workarounded by hosted the video in Azure storage account. Appreciate for your help!